# code language not supported or defined in VS code with html

Tags: javascript, php, html, visual-studio-code

After I installed the code runner extension and chromium browser support for VS code, The editor was working fine and when I run the page it asks which browser to pick when starting HTML as a markup language, but after I installed CCleaner and cleaned some system files, it stopped running.

I encountered the error message "**language not supported or defined**" when I launched the live server It does not work, I think there's a conflict between the "XAMPP server " and the live one, PHP works well, the question is how to make the run bottom configure HTML as it was, running quickly instead of copping its path and pasting it on a browser to save some time.

Everything works fine with PHP, JS, and other languages, except for HTML files, it compiles me to open it externally!

I read previous solutions as installing live server and modifying code runner extension, but none worked